# Laravel Eloquent Collection Search always returns false

Tags: database, laravel, search, collections, eloquent

When I use the Laravel Collection search function it always returns false.

Code :

```
$entries = Entry::all();
$results = $entries->search('Jack', true);
dd($results);
```

Output :`false`

Output dd($entries) :

```
    Collection {#218 ▼
  #items: array:9 [▼
    0 => Entry {#219 ▼
      #fillable: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▶]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Entry {#220 ▶}
    2 => Entry {#221 ▶}
    3 => Entry {#222 ▶}
    4 => Entry {#223 ▶}
    5 => Entry {#224 ▶}
    6 => Entry {#225 ▶}
    7 => Entry {#226 ▶}
    8 => Entry {#227 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Sorry for the horrible formatting.

Comment: Can you `dd($entries)` and post the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the Eloquence[0] package.

[0] = https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a simple collection with `search()` method. So, if you want to search for names, do this:

```
$entries = Entry::pluck('name');
$results = $entries->search('Jack');
```

BTW, this is a really bad way to do the search, because it will first load all entries into the memory and then will do the search.

A much better approach is to use Eloquent or Query Builder:

```
$results = Entry::where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
```

Or simply:

```
$results = Entry::where('name', $name)->get();
```

When you want to search for a whole name.

Comment: That is okay if I only want to search in the name column, but I want to use one search field to search all the entries for the given data..

Comment: @TenTimesCake then add multiple `orWhere()` clauses. Loading all the data and then using `search()` collections method is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `filter()` function of Laravel Collections:

```
$matchingRecords = $allRecords->filter(function($key, $record){
    return $record->name == "Jack";
});
```

Alternatives are the `first()` function to limit results to the first found, or `search()`.

Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any value in your collection holding `Jack` ? and not f.e. 'jack' ?

According to the docs
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout#searching

```
Entry::search('Jack')->get();
```

should do the trick, install the drivers tho.

Answer (score 0):

If applicable try with:

```
$collection->hasAny($needle)
```

In my case has solved.